# creating facebook fan pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to understand open graph objects behind facebook pages.

Actually I get there are basically these types of pages:

1. facebook fan pages
    (i.e. https://www.facebook.com/HuffingtonPost https://graph.facebook.com/HuffingtonPost )
2. websites fan pages **og:type != "article"**
   (i.e. http://wp.damore.it/?p=16 https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://wp.damore.it/?p=16 )
3. websites fan pages **og:type == "article"**
    (i.e. http://www.repubblica.it/politica/2011/09/26/news/brunetta_certificati-22244909/ https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.repubblica.it/politica/2011/09/26/news/brunetta_certificati-22244909/ )

As far as I know, I can update my fans only in case 1 and 2.
 
In case 2 a fan page is created into facebook, but is reachable only to admin users.

The questions are:

- This explanation is correct or am I missing something?
- Are these all existing fan pages types?
- Where I can find a comprehensive documentation that explain how to updates facebook pages fans?

Thanks to everybody want make clear such questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all your assumptions are correct.

In the case of 3, we don't allow you to update fans, since an article is a transient thing, not something you'd push further info into News Feed about.

Updating fans is covered in the Publishing section of this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

Comment: Thanks. Nothing about other fan pages types?

Comment: I mean, from a technical perspective they're all very similar to each other, but I'm not sure what you mean by "fan page types"

Comment: Web page that use the Open Graph protocol are equivalent to Facebook pages. This means when a user clicks a Like button on these pages, a connection is made between pages and the user and we have the ability to publish updates to the user. 
I'm interested to understand exactly in which pages this happens.

Comment: That happens with every type but article.